# Github Actions - Workflow is slow on using self-hosted runner vs running locally on the same system

Tags: unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, github-actions

While running my workflow on my self-hosted runner it takes me about 1hr 40mins or sometimes doesn't finish while doing the same thing on the same system locally takes about 15mins. I made sure i was running the same code and there was no difference between both the builds.

For context i am exporting an iOS Xcode project from unity via command line.

This is a huge difference and i am unsure why this might be the case. I am new to CI/CD and devops in general and wanted to understand why it might be the case. I tried looking on google but could not find the answer to this.

Thanks & Cheers.

Comment: I've only tried local CI/CD with Unity once and builds did just take longer, I think that's just how CI/CD works, its not designed to take up your system's full reasoures, but just run slowly in the background. Are there perhaps setting in your build tool to give it more reasources?

Answer (score 0):

If your local process does not need to communicate with GitHub Actions, that could explain the difference.

The [communication between self-hosted runners and GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#communication-between-self-hosted-runners-and-github) means:

> The self-hosted runner connects to GitHub to receive job assignments and to download new versions of the runner application.
>
> The self-hosted runner uses an HTTPS long poll that opens a connection to GitHub for 50 seconds, and if no response is received, it then times out and creates a new long poll.
> The application must be running on the machine to accept and run GitHub Actions jobs.

All that back-and-forth between your machine and GitHub could add overhead that your local execution (outside any GitHub runner) do not need to do.

Comment: Hi thanks for response. The time difference i am mainly talking about is for the time it take to export the unity xcode project i.e the time when the xcode export starts and ends for which i don't really believe there would be much talking between github and my self-hosted runner. But as i said i am new to this so i am not sure on that.

Comment: @ArnavSanghavi I agree. Is there any [log message](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/log-messages-cnsl1012/mac) during the self-hosted runer execution which could give you a clue?

Comment: from what i can tell there are a lot of Well known commands executing, on the runner log which might also mean its just waiting for something to happen.

Comment: @ArnavSanghavi Maybe the authentication part is slower? (as in [issue 1055](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1055))

Comment: that might be true. but from reading the issue and its comments I don't feel like that's the case. also while looking at the logs they don't really say anything to back that up or at least they don't look similar.

Comment: @ArnavSanghavi OK. Let us know if you find anything new in those logs or further workflow executions which could add some clues.